# Using xmlrpclib with cookie obtained different way

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

How can I use xmlrpclib in Python script to connect to xmlrpc service that requires authentication, but without using xmlrpc authentication?

To be specific:

1. I use Drupal 7.8, there is of course service modules, I will use it's methods like node.create..
2. Authentication to any HTTP address on this server is required by Shibboleth SSO
3. I would like to use services but there is no way of loggin to Shibboleth by xmlrpc (I have to simulate regular living user actions, parse html etc).
4. I managed to get a cookie (login successful) ready in a variable
5. Now I want to login to services via xmlrpclib.Server("...") but using the cookie I obtained in different way.

   Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify headers of a request from xmlrpclib client. Create a custom Transport class, and in its send_host method (I think?), you can modify the header to add the cookie you recieved.

**EDIT**

Check [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/501148-xmlrpc-serverclient-which-does-cookie-handling-and/)

Comment: Ok, I will try and follow this hint.